# Finding single object in database using Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework, ebean, playframework-2.4

I setup a plain **Play Framework - Java** project in version 2.4. And it is very easy to create a custom model object and to return a list of them. I am persisting the objects using ebean.

But how can I return a single object using **GET**?

**routes:**

```
GET     /payments/:id          controllers.Application.getPayment(id: Long)
```

And the controller tries to find the object byId:

```
public Result getPayment(Long id) {
    Payment payment = Payment.find.byId(id);
    return ok(toJson(payment));
}
```

But my app does not know what `find` is.

[image]

I followed the instruction on the official [Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaEbean).

Edit: my Payment.class

```
package models;

import com.avaje.ebean.Model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Payment extends Model {

@Id
Long id;
String name;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Comment: please show your Payment class

Comment: @cosmolev I updated my post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Payment class does not have `find` field.

Add this:

```
public static Finder<Long,Payment> find = new Finder<>(Long.class,Payment.class);
```